# Trigger an animation on an element's ::after when the element is clicked(::active) with css

Tags: css

Look My animation.

I made this for using a button for showing and hiding passwords.

```css
.eye{
    margin: 50px;
    color: black;
    transition-duration: .3s;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 10px solid currentColor;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-radius: 90px 5px;
    opacity: .5
}
.eye::before{
    content: "";
    border: 10px solid currentColor;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: currentColor;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 12px;
    
}

.eye::after{
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 7.5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 175px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: currentColor;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -35px
}

.eye:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
.eye:active{
    color: rgb(174, 0, 0);
    /* .eye::before{
    animation: slash infinite 5s;
    } */
}
@keyframes slash{
    from{width:1px;}
    to{width:175px}
}
```

```html
<div class="eye"></div>
```

look that...

I want to run the animation `slash` on `.eye::after`

when the `.eye` is `:active`

and also make it so until again click(that is once the eye is clicked draw a slash and make it show until the again click )

that is I want to trigger the `slash` animation on `.eye::after` when `.eye:active` is triggered ***only using css***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added an example, you don't need to use @keyframes and animation to animate this eye on click - just use transitions. Also, example works with `:active` pseudo-class as you use it in your example, but looks like you need to have it switch on click, that way just add and remove class `.active` on click and replace `:active` with `.active` in CSS

```css
.eye{
    margin: 50px;
    color: black;
    width: 100px;
    height:100px;
    border: 10px solid currentColor;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    border-radius: 90px 5px;
    opacity: .5;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}
.eye::before{
    content: "";
    border: 10px solid currentColor;
    width: 50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color: currentColor;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 12px;
}

.eye::after{
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 7.5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
    width: 0;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: currentColor;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -35px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.eye:hover{
    opacity: 1;
}
.eye:active{
    color: rgb(174, 0, 0);
}

.eye:active::after{
    width: 175px;
    background-color: rgb(174, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="eye"></div>
```

Comment: nice... I liked it. But, I have updated the question. Please have a look and don't change this.

Comment: @Musafiroon well, looks like you add quite big addition to your question, maybe you'll ask one more question for that purpose?

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve this by just simply adding one liner code of javascript i.e.  `classList.toggle()`

```js
const myfun = () => {
  const eye = document.querySelector(".eye");
  eye.classList.toggle('changed')

};
```

```css
.eye{
  margin: 50px;
  color: black;
  transition-duration: .3s;
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  border: 10px solid currentColor;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-radius: 90px 5px;
  opacity: .5
}
.eye::before{
  content: "";
  border: 10px solid currentColor;
  width: 50px;
  height:50px;
  background-color: currentColor;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-left: 12px;

}

.eye::after{
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 7.5px solid rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 0px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: currentColor;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -35px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.changed:after {
  width: 175px;
  transition: 1s;
}

.eye:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
.eye:active{
  color: rgb(174, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="style.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="eye" onclick="myfun()"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```